# How to provide separate service instances for multiple child components in Angular 2

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have an application which has multiple cases of a fairly similar master-details view with a search box. So I decided to wrap the common functionality into its own module with communication between the components achieved through a service. Here is the hierarchy:

```
MyGenericGridModule
    SearchComponent
    MasterGridComponent
    DetailsComponent
    GridService <-- stateful

AppModule
    CitiesGridComponent
    RetailersGridComponent
```

I intend to create multiple views of `MyGenericGridComponent` where the layout differences will be achieved through css. Here is quick illustration:
[image]
How do I ensure that I provide separate instances of the `GridService` to both dependent components?

I haven't found reading material so far that showcases this scenario. What I have read mentions Services should be shared and singletons. This leads me to believe I am tackling this problem incorrectly. Is there a more suitable pattern I can structure the components?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection

Comment: @R.Richards link is the right place to start - to have a separate instance of your `GridService` injected, I think you need to provide that via the `providers` data on both the `CitiesGridComponent` and `RetailersGridComponent`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Injecting the `GridService` at the component level would mean you get a different instance for each component, rather than a single instance from the parent injector e.g.:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GridService } from '../grid.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cities-grid',
  templateUrl: './cities-grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cities-grid.component.css'],
  providers: [GridService]
})
export class CitiesGridComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(gridSvc: GridService) { }
```

In addition to the links provided in the comments, this link to [providing services in components](https://angular.io/guide/providers#providing-services-in-modules-vs-components) from the Angular documentation seems aligned with your scenario.